# How to echo each line out for bash psql

Tags: bash, psql

Hi I am trying to echo each line out for the output of the psql. But now sure how to do that, right now the output is the error_message column with two lines. error_type1 error_type2

```
error_type=$(psql \
        -X \
        -U $DB_USER \
        -h $DB_HOST \
        -d $DB_NAME \
        -p $DB_PORT \
        --single-transaction \
        --set AUTOCOMMIT=off \
        --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on \
        --no-align \
        -t \
        --field-separator ' ' \
        --quiet \
        -c "SELECT error_message
            FROM _message
            ")

echo $ error_type
```

Comment: There should be no space between the `$` and `error_type`. the value of the variable is printed with: `echo $error_type`. Also when posting a question, please, share the output of your script. It will help to see what the problem is.

Comment: If you will not use the output of the `plsql` command later, you do not need to store it in a variable.  Just put the `plsql` command directly in the script, no `$( )` around it.  Done.  A good resource to know about for shell stuff is: https://www.shellcheck.net/